# Flip complete UITabView on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, uitabbar, flip

I have a TabView based application on the iPhone. On initial loading, I want to flip-animate the screen for showing some settings.

In my AppDelegate, the TabView is added to the window with

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

I browsed the web and found this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView:tabBarController.view
                         cache:YES];
[window addSubview:settingsViewController.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But when I test this in the simulator the only change I can see is that the TabMenu floats from right to left.

Can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could present the settings view as a modal view.  You can specify the animation to flip from right to left.

```
[settingsViewController.view setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];
```

To return:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked. But I had to insert a navigationController:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController];

[navigationController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

[navigationController release];
[settingsViewController release];
```

But now the next question: **How do I get back? :)**